# How to set line height for a single line text in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

Currently, I have been using `.lineSpacing(...)`, but this **only works for multi-line text**.

```
/// Sets the amount of space between lines of text in this view.
///
/// - Parameter lineSpacing: The amount of space between the bottom of one
///   line and the top of the next line.
@inlinable public func lineSpacing(_ lineSpacing: CGFloat) -> some View
```

What this means is that it's harder for me to translate fonts exactly from sketch/figma, and I need to play around with the padding to get it right. Here is an example that shows this:

```
VStack {
    // Line spacing is ignored.
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .background(Color.green)
        .lineSpacing(50)

    Spacer()

    // Line spacing is correct.
    Text("Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.")
        .background(Color.green)
        .lineSpacing(50)
}
```

Comment: I did not get your point but, try this if it works for you: Add "\n" at the end of One line `Text`

Comment: What would you expect for first Text? How fonts relates to the topic - the are same in both Text blocks?

Comment: @EnesKaraosman I don't want to add a new line, I want to increase the space of a single line.

Comment: Does that help to clarify @EnesKaraosman?

Comment: I cannot convince myself, how a single line should have spacing. `lineSpacing` the method name is clear, also you've visited SwiftUI's interface to read the explanation, there also been said, "Sets the amount of space between *lines*..." :(

Comment: SwiftUI text does not provide a lineHeight property (line spacing is a different beast). You could try to align the 'firstTextBaseLine' to get the desired behaviour. Alternatively, use a 'UILabel' (via 'UIViewRepresentable') with an attributed string (specify line height in the paragraph style).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Based on the answer by [Dan Hassan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13835223/dan-hassan) I made myself a ViewModifier to do this, and it looks like it works as intended

```
import SwiftUI

struct FontWithLineHeight: ViewModifier {
    let font: UIFont
    let lineHeight: CGFloat

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(Font(font))
            .lineSpacing(lineHeight - font.lineHeight)
            .padding(.vertical, (lineHeight - font.lineHeight) / 2)
    }
}

extension View {
    func fontWithLineHeight(font: UIFont, lineHeight: CGFloat) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: FontWithLineHeight(font: font, lineHeight: lineHeight))
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably better to update this to use `Font` instead? Or can't access `lineHeight` from SwiftUI font?

Comment: Correct, Font does not have the lineHeight, so thats why I had to go through UIFont.

Comment: I a just lazy on the `UIFont` initializer; if I get the time, will post an update that takes in size, weight, and line space, all in one call.

Comment: Anyone figure out a solution for negative `.lineSpacing`? Seems like if you pass in a negative number it is treated as 0.

Comment: The view extension method can be simplified to `modifier(FontWithLineHeight(font: font, lineHeight: lineHeight))`

Comment: I've noticed that this results in a slightly different spacing than UIKit's minimumLineHeight. Does anybody have insight?

Answer (score 17):

For getting your text to match figma here's what finally worked for me. If for example your figma designs had a particular font of 16 pt with a line height of 32 pt:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "SomeFont", size: 16)!
return Text("Some Text")
    .font(.custom("SomeFont", size: 16))
    .lineSpacing(32 - font.lineHeight)
    .padding(.vertical, (32 - font.lineHeight) / 2)
```

In order to get the exact line spacing value we have to subtract our desired line height by the font's inherent line height but as you noted this will only take effect on multiline text and only between lines. We still need to account for the top and bottom padding of the text to match the desired line height so once again add the total line height minus the font's line height.

Comment: Nice, putting this in a view modifier would be great ;)

Comment: This only works when you need to _increase_ the line spacing. If you want to make it condensed, it does not work and respects the default line height instead.

Comment: Is there a way to set negative lineSpacing or smaller lineHeight?

Answer (score 10):

**Xcode 12**

Use the `.leading()` modifier to adjust line spacing.

```
Text("Hello\nworld").font(Font.body.leading(.tight))
```

Currently supported values: `.tight`, `.standard` and `.loose`.

Source: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/leading(_:))

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but still pretty cool you can do this! Maybe sticking to either of these three options is better than getting actual values from designers, but sometimes, designs are designs, so can't default to application standards.

Answer (score 3):

Actually what worked for me was (based on the answer by Ole-Kristian)

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FontWithLineHeight: ViewModifier {
    let font: UIFont
    let lineHeight: CGFloat

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(Font(font))
            .lineSpacing((token.lineHeight - token.font.lineHeight)/2)
            .padding(.vertical, (token.lineHeight - token.font.lineHeight))
    }
}

extension View {
    func fontWithLineHeight(font: UIFont, lineHeight: CGFloat) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: FontWithLineHeight(font: font, lineHeight: lineHeight))
    }
}
```

...very similar to the other answers with values for padding and lineSpacing reversed.

This was the only way I could get the bottom 'padding' to be the same as Figma.

Comment: what would `token` be here?

Answer (score 1):

I have been successfully using the following combination:

- `.frame(minHeight: lineHeight)`
- `.lineSpacing(abs(designSystemFont.lineHeight - uiKitFont.lineHeight))`

> *The `abs` may not be needed (assuming the system's line height is taller than the default one, but you never know if that may change, so...)*

This allows me to handle for handling single-line text while respecting the design system requirements.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 17+ with UIKit `NSMutableParagraphStyle`

```swift
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
// iOS 15/16 seems not working
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 21
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 21

var attributedString = AttributedString(text)
attributedString.paragraphStyle = paragraphStyle

Text(attributedString)
```

Comment: How did you figure out that it worked for ios 17+? It unfortunately doesn't work for me on ios 17.2...

Answer (score -2):

You can just use .frame modifier and set the height.

Comment: I would rather a avoid hard coded frame size as this would not be automatically adjusted as the font, layout, or the content changes.