# How to add line-height for multiline text in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have multiline text for which I want to give specific line-height.
I tried with linespacing but I can see no changes.

Please help with the above query.

Thank you for help

Comment: `lineSpacing` should be the way to do this. Show us some code as well as screenshots of what it looks like with and without the `lineSpacing` modifier.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61705184/how-to-set-line-height-for-a-single-line-text-in-swiftui/63273624#63273624 ) seems relevant. Peep the answer by Ole-Kristian.